# Attempt to index upvalue

Tags: lua, coronasdk, upvalue

I have just started learning Lua today. I have been doing the tutorials on coronalabs.com website... I tried to adapt a the first exercise with tapping the bouncing balloon into the scenes template of the asteroids games. Can someone tell me how I am "attempting to index an upvalue"?

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()


-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Code outside of the scene event functions below will only be executed ONCE unless
-- the scene is removed entirely (not recycled) via "composer.removeScene()"
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()

local tapCount = 0
local platform
local balloon
local tapText

local function pushBalloon()
     balloon:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -0.75, balloon.x, balloon.y )
     tapCount = tapCount + 1
     tapText.text = tapCount

end



-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scene event functions
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- create()
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs when the scene is first created but has not yet appeared on screen
physics.pause()
local background = display.newImageRect( "background.png", 360, 570 )
background.x = display.contentCenterX
background.y = display.contentCenterY
local platform = display.newImageRect( "platform.png", 300, 50 )
platform.x = display.contentCenterX
platform.y = display.contentHeight-25
local balloon = display.newImageRect( "balloon.png", 112, 112 )
balloon.x = display.contentCenterX
balloon.y = display.contentCenterY
balloon.alpha = 0.8

local tapText = display.newText( tapCount, display.contentCenterX, 20, native.systemFont, 40 )
tapText:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )


physics.addBody( platform, "static" )
physics.addBody( balloon, "dynamic", { radius=50, bounce=0.6 } )

balloon:addEventListener( "tap", pushBalloon )

end


-- show()
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is entirely on screen
physics.start()
    end
end


-- hide()
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs immediately after the scene goes entirely off screen
physics.pause()
    end
end


-- destroy()
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs prior to the removal of scene's view

end


-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scene event function listeners
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: At what line # the error raised?

Comment: Code above don't produce any errors in my simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upvalue in question is a local variable external to the function.  When you initialize `balloon` in `scene:create()`, you are declaring it `local`, which is limiting the scope of **that** `balloon` to the function.  Outside of `scene:create()`, the `balloon` declared near the top of your file is still `nil`.

Remove `local` before `balloon` in `scene:create()` and everything should work.  In other words, change

```
    local balloon = display.newImageRect(...
```

to

```
    balloon = display.newImageRect(...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`:` is one of the indexing operators. `.` and `[]` are the others. An indexing operation evaluates the value of the left expression, expecting a table value. If it is one, it looks for a key in that table equal to the value of the expression inside the `[]` or equal to the identifier on the right of `:` or `.` as a string value. If there is no table, an error is thrown.

An upvalue is a reference to a non-global variable that is declared `local` in an outer function scope. You have a lot of those and that's fine, particularly with variables that are global-like, singleton in nature and are effectively services/libraries. For example, `composer` and `scene`.

Desk checking suggests that the error is thrown at `balloon:applyLinearImpulse`. [GoojajiGreg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880366/2226988) explains how to correct your code so that `balloon` refers to a table at that point in the execution, as expected.